# Low accuracy on binary classification problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-classification

I'm trying to build a classification model to recognize the point of view of pictures in interior design. For the moment, I consider only two classes: sofa_left and sofa_right depending on the orientation of the sofa [(see examples)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru5bm.png).

I used the very same code like this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) for transfer learning (based on MobileNetV2 with imagenet weights).

**There is no problem with the code: I can reproduce the expected results with the provided dataset of cats and dogs.**

Here is the model summary if it can help.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_31 (InputLayer)        [(None, 160, 160, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice (T [(None, 160, 160, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_BiasAdd (TensorF [(None, 160, 160, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
resnet50 (Functional)        (None, 5, 5, 2048)        23587712  
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_15  (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 2049      
=================================================================
Total params: 23,589,761
Trainable params: 2,049
Non-trainable params: 23,587,712
_________________________________________________________________
```

Yet, results are really poor with my own images (50% accuracy...) and I can't figure out why.
There are dropouts in the model, I tried many settings (learning rate, validation split, batch size), and many pre-trained models.

I have around 150 pictures for each class. I know it's not a big dataset, but I don't need to generalize too much, all pictures I need to test will are of the same kind. Is it too short?

I ran a `kmeans clustering` algorithm on predictions made from the MobileNetV2 on the dataset and tada... pictures are perfectly sorted between sofa_left and sofa_right. It gives me the intuition this classification problem should be solvable using learning. Am I right?
Am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would first try cat vs sofa.  Should work.  If not, you have a model issue.  Otherwise, not that CONVnets can't encode position, but my intuition is that it's not what they are best at.

Comment: Thanks for the input ! I tried sofa (front view) vs sofa (left and front) and I get pretty good results indeed. It seems your intuition is good. However, do you have any idea why the kmean algorithm perform so well ? I ran the Kmean on the features resulting on predictions from resnet50.

Comment: When you say predictions, do you mean just the output of the last convolution layer of resnet50?

Comment: Nevermind, you probably mean the raw logits of the dense layer.  Make sure your loss has (from_logits=True)

Comment: Indeed it was the raw logits of the last layer, loss function as the from_logits. I used another dataset (mixed all sofa left/right, add different framing with other point of view such as kitchen and front sofa). My val accuracy is much higher (85%). Thank you for your inputs.